# Intuition behind using dot product to find component of vector in direction of another

Tags: physics, vector-spaces

I'm reading Chris Hecker's third article on rigid body dynamics
http://chrishecker.com/Rigid_body_dynamics

Quoting...

"More importantly, if our collision
detector supplies us with a 'normal vector' for the collision (denoted by n, and
pointing toward body A by convention),
we can define the 'relative normal
velocity' as the **component of the relative velocity in the direction of the collision normal**."

Which he defines as vAB . n where vab is the relative velocity of points A and B and n is the normal vector for the collision.

I read [Understanding Dot and Cross Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77/understanding-dot-and-cross-product) which explains that the dot product gives the length of one vector in the direction of another, which I think is what is being applied here, but I'm having a really hard time visualizing what is going on, specifically what the component is.

Can anyone help explain what this component is and how using the dot product helps identify it?

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have vectors ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$, you can write ${\bf x}={\bf u}+{\bf v}$, where ${\bf u}$ is parallel ("in the direction of") ${\bf y}$ and ${\bf v}$ is perpendicular to ${\bf y}$. Visually, drop a perpendicular from ${\bf x}$ onto ${\bf y}$ (first extending $\bf y$, if necessary), then that perpendicular is $\bf v$ and the vector from the origin to the foot of the perpendicular is $\bf u$.

Now from ${\bf x}={\bf u}+{\bf v}$ you get ${\bf x}\cdot{\bf u}={\bf u}\cdot{\bf u}+{\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}$. Now ${\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}=0$ since $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ are perpendicular, and ${\bf u}\cdot{\bf u}$ is the square of the length of $\bf u$, so ${\bf x}\cdot{\bf u}=\|{\bf u}\|^2$. That gives you the interpretation of the dot product in terms of the component of one vector in the direction of another.