# Cross Product. How does this: `C = A x B` formula used correctly?

Tags: cross-product

I don't understand how this: `C = A x B` formula works, Does the "x" means multiply?

If the vector **a** = 5 (magnitude) is going into the screen, then **b** = 7 is going up... Why the Cross product goes right? how does this: `C = A x B` formula used correctly? Do I just simply multiply 7 to 5 and get 35?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd2Gi.png

Comment: If $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ happen to be orthogonal, then their cross product will have magnitude $35$.  But that's not the case if they're at any other angle to one another.

Comment: You can get the cross product symbol with \times, so C=A \times B renders as $C=A\times B$

Comment: I suggest you take a bit to [peruse some of the past questions on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20cross%20product).  In particular, [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62318/origin-of-the-dot-and-cross-product), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941044/why-is-cross-product-defined-in-the-way-that-it-is), and [4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77/understanding-dot-and-cross-product) should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of $A \times B$ is $|A||B|\sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.  In your example the vectors are orthogonal, so the angle is $\frac \pi 2$ and the $\sin$ is $1$.  If the vectors are not orthogonal the length of the cross product will not be the product of the lengths.  Try $(1,0,0) \times (1,1,0)$.  The lengths are $1, \sqrt 2$ but the cross product is $(0,0,1)$ with length $1$.