# Why do we care about the general outer product $\mathbf u\otimes\mathbf v=\mathbf u\mathbf v^{\sf T}$?

Tags: soft-question, outer-product

- [Why](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77/347062) do we care about dot and cross products?
- [Why](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240491/what-is-a-covector-and-what-is-it-used-for) do we care about covectors? [essentially is the meaning of the question]
- [Why](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/why-do-we-care-about-dual-spaces) do we care about dual spaces?

So, why do we care about the general outer product $\mathbf u\otimes\mathbf v=\mathbf u\mathbf v^{\sf T}$?

I understand what it is, but why do we need it? It’s related to the cross product I understand, but why doesn’t that suffice?

Comment: If $u$ is an unit vector, then $u u^{T}$ is the projector to $u$.

Comment: @Botond What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

The outer product $u v^T$ more often than not appears as an operator; for instance, as [Botond](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/281471/botond) pointed out, if $u$ is a unit vector, then $P_u = uu^T$ is the projector onto the $u$.

There are, however, many other uses. Some of which are:

### Spectral decomposition of operators

We can express a matrix as the sum of outer products of its eigenvectors according to
$$A = \lambda_1 u_1 v_1^T + \cdots \lambda_n u_n v_n^T,$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue and $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the $i$th right and left eigenvectors of $A$. This is sometimes called the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

This is idea from linear algebra that can be extended to general [spectral theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory) where they are used to represent [rank-1 operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-rank_operator). Rank one operators are used a lot in quantum mechanics: for instance, one central operator in [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm), known as *Grover's diffusion operator* is given by
$$ U_s = 2|s \rangle \langle s| - I,$$
where $|s \rangle \langle s|$ is the outer product of the vector
$|s\rangle$ in [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation).

### Rank-1 updates

In numerical algebra, we can have matrices that are updated partially. For instance, given $A^{-1}$ and two vector $u$ and $v$, we may need to compute
$$(A + uv^T)^{-1}.$$
This can be done with the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)
which gives us a numerically cheap way to compute the inverse of a matrix when it is perturbed by a rank-1 perturbation:
$$ (A + uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}u v^T A^{-1}}{1 + v^T A^{-1} u}.$$

A similar result holds for the determinant:
$$ \det(A +u v^T) = (1 + v^T A^{-1} u)\det(A).$$
This is called the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

### Duality with the inner product

A personal favorite of mine is to use of the duality between the inner product and the trace of the outer product:
$$ v^Tu = \mathrm{trace}\{uv^T\}.$$

For instance, it allows for an easy (and fun) computation of the expected value of a [$\chi^2$ random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). If $X$ is $\chi^2$ distributed with $n$ degrees of freedom, then it can be seen as the sum of the squares of $n$ standard normal random variables:
$$ X = E_1 ^2 + \cdots E_n^2.$$

Let $E$ be the vector whose $i$th component is $E_i$, then $E$ is an $n$ dimensional standard normal random vector,
$$E \sim N(0,I).$$

Hence,
$$ \mathbf E [X] = \mathbf E[E^TE] = \mathrm{trace}\{\mathbf E[ E E^T]\} = \mathrm{trace}\{I\} = n.$$

Comment: "Grover's diffusion operator" is a Householder transformation, so it describes a reflection.